# How can I make it so my encode/decoder only using certain ASCII characters

Tags: java, encoding, decode, encode

Doing a project, and I need to encode and decode a password I type in. My question is, how can I make it so my encode/decoder only uses ASCII characters 33-122?

I'll throw my code in, but I dont think it makes much of a difference

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String password;
      String encryptedPassword;
      int encryptionNumber;
      int passwordLength;
      char cypher;
      char decypher;
      
      System.out.println("Enter password. Has to be 8 characters or longer");
      password = kb.nextLine();
      
      passwordLength = password.length();
      while(passwordLength < 8)
      {
         if(passwordLength >= 8)
         {
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Your password is currently " + passwordLength + " characters long. The password needs 8 characters at least");
            password = kb.nextLine();
            passwordLength = password.length();
         }
      }
      
      System.out.println("Your password is " + password);
      
      System.out.println("Choose an encrpytion between 1 and 10");
      encryptionNumber = kb.nextInt();
      
      while(encryptionNumber < 1 || encryptionNumber>10)
      {
         if(encryptionNumber>=1 && encryptionNumber<= 10)
         {
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Choose a valid encryption key that is between 1 and 10");
            encryptionNumber = kb.nextInt();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("You chose encryption " + encryptionNumber);
      
      System.out.print("The encrypted password is: ");
      
      for(int i=0; i < passwordLength; i++)
      {
         cypher = (char)(password.charAt(i) + encryptionNumber);
         System.out.print(cypher);
      }
      System.out.println("");
      
      System.out.println("Now enter the encrypted password so it can be decrypted");
      encryptedPassword = kb1.nextLine();
      
      for(int i=0; i < passwordLength; i++)
      {
         decypher = (char)(encryptedPassword.charAt(i) - encryptionNumber);
         System.out.print(decypher);
      }
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Changed my code to this, works perfectly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. The best is to use regular expressions to validate your input. Read about class [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). More simplistic but not effective solution is to iterate through each character in your string and to validate it individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I changed to make it work

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String password;
      String encryptedPassword;
      int encryptionNumber;
      int passwordLength;
      char cypher;
      char decypher;
            
      System.out.println("Enter password. Has to be 8 characters or longer");
      password = kb.nextLine();
      
      //Checks to see of the password is greater than 8 characters
      passwordLength = password.length();
      while(passwordLength < 8)
      {
         if(passwordLength >= 8)
         {
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Your password is currently " + passwordLength + " characters long. The password needs 8 characters at least");
            password = kb.nextLine();
            passwordLength = password.length();
         }
      }
      
      System.out.println("Your password is " + password);
      
      System.out.println("Choose an encrpytion between 1 and 10");
      encryptionNumber = kb.nextInt();
      
      while(encryptionNumber < 1 || encryptionNumber>10)
      {
         if(encryptionNumber>=1 && encryptionNumber<= 10)
         {
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Choose a valid encryption key that is between 1 and 10");
            encryptionNumber = kb.nextInt();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("You chose encryption " + encryptionNumber);
      
      //Encrypts the password to give the user a new encrypted password
      System.out.print("The encrypted password is: ");
      
      for(int i=0; i < passwordLength; i++)
      {
         cypher = (char)(password.charAt(i) + encryptionNumber);
         if ((password.charAt(i) + encryptionNumber)>122)
         {
            cypher = (char)(((password.charAt(i) + encryptionNumber) - 122) + 32);
         }
         System.out.print(cypher);
      }
      System.out.println("");
      
      //Used to decrypt the password
      System.out.println("Now enter the encrypted password so it can be decrypted");
      encryptedPassword = kb1.nextLine();
      
      for(int i=0; i < passwordLength; i++)
      {
         decypher = (char)(encryptedPassword.charAt(i) - encryptionNumber);
         if ((encryptedPassword.charAt(i) - encryptionNumber)<33)
         {
            decypher = (char)(122 - (32 - (encryptedPassword.charAt(i) - encryptionNumber)));
         }
         System.out.print(decypher);
      }      
   }
}
```